# Can't use google-pinyin on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: input-method, chinese, fcitx, pinyin

I have google-pinyin installed:

```
$ sudo apt install -y fcitx-googlepinyin
...

$ apt list --installed *pinyin*
Listing... Done
fcitx-googlepinyin/jammy,now 0.1.6-5 amd64 [installed]
libgooglepinyin0/jammy,now 0.1.2-7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

[image]

After reboot, fcitx is working that I can set input method to `Google Pinyin` but just couldn't type anything non English. How can I use `Google Pinyin`?

(I'm trying to avoid `ibus-intelligent-pinyin`)

Comment: Note that fcitx is poorly maintained nowadays. It's being replaced by fcitx5, so if you don't have a strong preference for googlepinyin, I'd advise you to install fcitx5 instead and try e.g. fcitx5-pinyin.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 22.04, please try to install fcitx5 instead of fcitx.
Here are the commands I used to install fcitx5 on ubuntu 22.04 and above:

```
sudo apt install fcitx5 fcitx5-chineseaddons fcitx5-frontend-gtk fcitx5-configtool
```

Add the following lines to either ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile, to ensure fcitx5 are the default IM:

```
export XMODIFIERS=’@im=fcitx5’
export XMODIFIER=’@im=fcitx5’
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx5
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx5
export DefaultIMModule=fcitx5
```

Make sure fcitx5 is auto started with the system.

You'd better restart the system after all the above is done.

After you login to the system again, run fcitx5, configure it by looking for Chinese inputs like: pinyin, etc. Configure the global settings, e.g., IM trigger shortcut keys, etc.

Hope the above helps!